# Get top N values from each sub-array from 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've a 2 dimensional numpy array (Classification Model's probability output). Now I want to extract the index of top 3 values for each nested array.

E.g.

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 1]], np.int32)
```

What I want is

```
[[5, 4, 3]
[4, 3, 2]]
```

Without using loop

Comment: @asapokL Not really, OP is asking about how to retrieve the position of maximum numbers without loop, actually a method problem, related to unravel_index method.

Comment: np.argsort or argposition applied to the axis?

Comment: E.g. `np.argsort(x, axis=1)[:, :-4:-1]`

Comment: @jdehesa thanks your solution worked!!!

Comment: @asapokL please understand the question properly. There is no easy language than this, I could have explained.